# Late 70s sci-fi novel about inter-dimensional travel at will

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm hoping someone here can help identify or point me to a good resource for identifying a science fiction novel for a library patron.  Here are the details he remembers:

He read the book during a local blizzard of 1978, so it would be published that year or earlier.

The title may have mentioned something about infinity or light.

The protagonist could travel between dimensions at will; and light or "white light" was either a triggering mechanism or some kind of component.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/151844/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm mildly hesitant to post this, because it's later than the 1978 that you mention, but it fits pretty much all of the other points. If all else fails, it might help someone seeking a similar book.

*[White Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Light_(novel))* is a **1980** novel by Rudy Rucker. It features Felix Rayman, a down-and-out mathematics teacher, who learns to travel to other dimensions via lucid dreaming and "fuzz weed" (marijuana). The book is an exploration of the mathematics of infinity.

[image: Book cover from 1980]

So that has a title invoking white light, subject matter of infinity, and dimensional travel. The only thing that doesn't match is the date.

Comment: you answered this question at the speed of light too!

Comment: It came up right off in the Google search. :)

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising & I've emailed my patron to see if it's a match